# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string while saving

Tags: laravel-5.5

I'm working on a project where user id can't be auto increment and must follow a specific logic

In my Store function on userController i have

```
 $user=new User();

    if (is_null($numero)) {
        $user->numMembre=$section->secteur->id.$section_id.'0001';
    }
    else
    {
        $numMembre=$numero->numMembre+1;
        $user->numMembre=(print_r($numMembre,true));
    }
    $user->nom=$nom;
    $user->prenom=$prenom;
    $user->sexe=$sexe;
    $user->matrEnseignant=$matrEnseignant;
    $user->titreEnseignant=$titreEnseignant;
    $user->email=$email;
    $user->numero=$numero;
    $user->section_id=$section_id;
    $user->statut_id=$result;
    $user->password=bcrypt($password);
    $user->save();
```

But i'm getting "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"
on $user->save(); line

Comment: Using dd(), ensure that none of the variables used are returning an object

Comment: i have already done that